# PhpStorm and CodeSniffer do not recognize WPCS

Tags: php, wordpress, phpstorm, standards, phpcodesniffer

I'm trying to use WordPress Coding Standards in my PhpStorm projects but I keep getting errors.

What I already did:

1 - I put it in composer.json:

```json
"require": { "squizlabs/php_codesniffer" : "3.*", "wp-coding-standards/wpcs": "2.3.0" }
```

2 - I configured CodeSniffer in the Quality Tools section

3 - In `Inspections -> PHP -> Quality Tools` I put WordPress in Coding Standard.

[image: Image 1 - Inspection setting]

**The issue:**

Even though I've done all this, I'm still not able to evaluate the code from WPCS. The following error is returned:

> ERROR: The file "standard=WordPress" does not exist.

When I type `phpcs -i`, WordPress doesn't show up either, and when I try to evaluate the file it does not work also (Image 2 below):

> The installed coding standards are MySource, PEAR, PSR1, PSR12, PSR2, Squiz and Zend

[image: Image 2 - PHPCS Messages]

Can someone help me?

**System details:**

PhpStorm 2020.2.1
Windows 11
Composer global installation

Comment: These instructions work for me. https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/wordpress-aware-coding-assistance.html

Comment: What do you have under PHP > Quality Tools > PHP_Codesniffer configuration - click the 3 dots.

Comment: @O.Jones for me didnt work. I tried a lot.

Comment: @HowardE, PHP_CodeSniffer path: C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-content\plugins\lb-status-message\vendor\bin\phpcs.bat and Path to phpcbf: C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-content\plugins\lb-status-message\vendor\bin\phpcbf.bat

Comment: Did you perform the installation instructions as described at WPCS package site? Namely you need to add WPCS via `--config-set`, e.g. `./bin/phpcs --config-set installed_paths ../wpcs`, see the bottom part of https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress-Coding-Standards#standalone